# Exclude duplicate rows in query result

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to count the number of records in database from more than two tables that are joined.

For example I have a table like this.

```
table
jobd  +  name
    1  |  jobA
    2  |  jobB

tableA
imgeid  +  orderid   +    jobid   
      1 |  1         |    1
      2 |  2         |    1
      3 |  3         |    1
      4 |  4         |    1    (this order is not yet started)

tableB
taskid  +  orderid   +    task  +  status
      1 |  1         |    1     |  UPDATED
      2 |  1         |    1     |  UPDATED
      3 |  1         |    1     |  COMPLETED
      4 |  2         |    2     |  SAVED
      5 |  3         |    3     |  COMPLETED
```

My problem here is that when I count base on status (@ tableB) my query results both the UPDATED which has the same orderid.

This is my sample query that same with the one I'm working.

```
SELECT t.name
    COUNT(CASE WHEN tb.task = 1 AND tb.status <> 'COMPLETED' THEN tb.status ELSE NULL END) inprogress,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN tb.task = 1 AND tb.status = 'COMPLETED' THEN tb.status ELSE NULL END) completed
FROM tableA ta
LEFT JOIN tableB tb
    ON tb.orderid = ta.orderid
LEFT JOIN table t
    ON t.jobid = ta.jobid
GROUP BY t.jobid;
```

My results something like

```
name   +    inprogress     +   completed
jobA   |    2              |   1
```

The inprogress results must only be 1 because it has the same orderid. The reason why it has two UPDATED because this table is HISTORICAL. I don't know how can get the distinct orderid in tableB so it will only results to 1.

The main point here is that I can count the total orders which status is in progress, completed and not started per job.

I hope my question is clear. If you have other way, please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Can't you use a Count distinct? Here's a link, see nearer the bottom of the page, it will only the unique field you specify: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp

Comment: I already think about it. But I don't know how can I apply with my current COUNT(CASE......)) If it will be like this COUNT(DISTINCT(??? what's the next things to do so I can still use my CASE condition. Or where should I put the DISTINCT in my query.Thanks

Comment: SELECT t.name
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN tb.task = 1 AND tb.status <> 'COMPLETED' THEN tb.status ELSE NULL END) inprogress,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN tb.task = 1 AND tb.status = 'COMPLETED' THEN tb.status ELSE NULL END) completed

Comment: I already use that but I'm getting only a result of 1 in my live query. My result should be 3 when without DISTINCT it shows 59.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you use a Count distinct? Here's a link, see nearer the bottom of the page, it will only the unique field you specify: w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp

```
SELECT t.name
COUNT(DISTINCT tb.orderid CASE WHEN tb.task = 1 AND tb.status  'COMPLETED' THEN tb.status
ELSE NULL END) inprogress,
COUNT(DISTINCT tb.orderid CASE WHEN tb.task = 1 AND tb.status = 'COMPLETED' THEN tb.status
ELSE NULL END) completed
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I find out what missing in my code. I did not include the column name of the table. It has something to be like this COUNT(DISTINCT tb.orderid, CASE WHEN tb.task = 1 AND tb.status  'COMPLETED' THEN tb.status ELSE NULL END) inprogress

Comment: Cool,I'll amend it in case anyone else needs it for reference.

Comment: Yeah!.. but now I get another problem... I should not include orderid which have COMPLETED status in in-progress. I guess this is more problematic if you have idea please post it or do I need to post new question. Anyway Thanks..